# Recreating live wallpaper after rotation

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

How can I detect changing device orientation and recreate surface in my WallpaperService? Now surface successfully create in one orientation, but when I make rotation, surface doesn't recreate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just need to detect orientation change...

see [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)

for an example see here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Ok, it is good, but how can I call onSurfaceChanged in onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: just put the onConfigurationChanged in your activity. You are overriding it (@Override) from the superclass Activity.

Comment: I don't have Activity. I use WallpaperService

Comment: Create inner class that extends Engine. WallpaperService.Engine contains the method onSurfaceChanged(). You can get the orientation from there.